# SPOJ: The day of the competitors

Tags: c, algorithm

I am trying to solve the problem The day of the competitors on [SPOJ](http://www.spoj.com/problems/NICEDAY/). I tried the following approach:

I am finding the best initial players, so initially the ones with 1st position are the best ones. After this I iterate over all the players and for each of them try to see if any of the current best ones are better than this, if so then this is not excellent discard it(as there exists some player better than this), otherwise I will add it to the best player list. In the end I will output the number of best players.

```
    for(i=0; i<num; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<ctr; j++)
        {               
            // i is already in best
            if(i == best_n[j])
                break;                        
            if((elmts[i].a < elmts[best_n[j]].a) ||
                    (elmts[i].b < elmts[best_n[j]].b) ||
                    (elmts[i].c < elmts[best_n[j]].c))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(j>=ctr)
        {
            best_n[ctr] = i;
            ctr ++;
        }
    }
```

num is number of players, and ctr is number of players in best array till now. But I am getting a wrong answer. I tried to again run a loop for verifying among the best if any player is worse than any other but that also results in a wrong answer. Also I don't think my method is efficient it would be n^2 in worst case. Could you please help me in figuring my mistake and how can I improve this to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is see is that your algorithm needs to remove all elements in `best_n` that the current is better than.

Consider:

```
1 5 5 // inserted into best at start
5 1 1 // inserted into best at start
3 4 4 // not worse than any of the above, insert into best
4 3 3 // not worse than any of the above, insert into best
2 2 2 // better than 3 4 4 and 4 3 3
```

The (pseudo-)code will look something like: (if the current is better in EVERY contest, we must replace the other one with the current)

```
// define '<' as 'better than'
if (not best[j] < elmts[i])
  if (elmts[i] < best[j])
    remove best[j]
    ctr--
  continue
else break
```

**Efficient solution:**

`O(n^2)` is likely too slow. [Here](http://apps.topcoder.com/forums/?module=Thread&threadID=575041&messageID=801760&mc=15&view=tree#801760) is a high-level overview of an efficient solution. [Here](https://github.com/zobayer1/SPOJ/blob/master/NICEDAY.cpp) is C++ code which presumably works.

Comment: Don't you think for ranking higher the value should be smaller thus '<' makes sense? I agree I need to remove in this case but even after removing such items, the verdict is wrong answer. Could you please point me to a different efficient approach.

Comment: I am still not convinced why I need to change the comparison operator, If I do that then, any player who is worse than all the best players in any match would be added to the best set, isn't it wrong? In current code if the current player is better than all the best players in any one match will be added as no player can be better than this player. May be I don't understand your logic.

Comment: You are mistaking in considering the criteria, A is better than B if and only if (A.a < B.a)
    && (A.b < B.b)
    && (A.c < B.c)

Comment: But still we haven't been able to find the reason of wrong answer. :( Do I post complete code?

Comment: @gaurav I found another problem. Edited appropriately. Not 100% sure if the way you're trying to do things will cover every test case. You can post complete code, but preferably to somewhere like pastebin.com rather than in your question, an answer or a comment, though I'm not sure it'll help.

Comment: Sorry, I am trying to understand the i/p and o/p mentioned in the link pointed by OP. How is the output / answer 3 for that test case?

Comment: @goldenmean Does it make more sense if I rephrase it as "find the number of contestants that are better at at least one competition than each other contestant". Thus `123` is better than the 2nd and 3rd contestants at the 1st competition (or better than 3 at competition 1 and better than 2 at competition 2), `231` is better at the 3rd and `312` is better at the 2nd, thus 3.

Comment: @Dukeling - Thanks. So output expected is total number of contestants which are excellent. I misunderstood it as the contestant's number. So basically in that example since each contestant has rank 1 in exactly one competition, the total number of excellent contestants is 3. IS this understanding correct. If yes, then Well now I need to sit with a pen paper for the solution :).. thanks

Comment: @Dukeling : Ok I have pasted the code here http://pastebin.com/1YaZqAFn , Please have a look at it.

Comment: @gaurav **(1)** I don't think `for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--)` covers everything (what if `best_n[j]` is better than `best_n[i]` for `j > i`), I think it needs to be `for(j=ctr-1;j>=0;j--)`? **(2)** What if more than 1 `j` is better than `i`? You need to swap your check around (`best_n[i]` better than `best_n[j]`) and `best_n[i (now j)] = -1; count--;` needs to be where `break` is now.

Comment: @Dukeling: (1) : Thanks for pointing that out, I was thinking that because of outer loop every element will be covered, but for any j>i the condition would not be checked. (2): Doesn't it suffice that if one j is found satisfying that condition we don't need to check for any other j. How does it help, I didn't understand?

Comment: @Dukeling : I made change according to (1) : I am getting TLE now. :(

Comment: @gaurav **(2)** I may have not thought that through. **(3)** [I made some changes](http://pastebin.com/T98CdUgJ) **(edited)** that should be more efficient. See if you understand + agree. If this still gives a TLE, I don't think there's much to be done, then you'll have implement the suggested solution (you could keep track of the j value for when `best_n[j] = -1` and replace that one rather than insert at the end, but that's a small change).

Comment: @Dukeling: I understand your suggestion, I changed the code according to your suggestion, but I am still getting a TLE. :(. I think keeping track of the value would also incur some complexity. I think I would look at that nlogn solution only